# jQuery UI - Connect lists over an accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Please see the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CK9uL/134/

I can drag items from the right to the headers on the left and sort them under each header.

I'm now trying to drag items *between* headers.

I have tried the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#droppable ul").sortable({
        connectWith: $('.connectWith')
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

But the lists don't seem to be connecting. Any ideas?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/), the `connectWith` property takes a selector, not a jQuery object. Assuming you have other sortables with the `connectWith` class, the following should work:

```
$(function() {
    $("#droppable ul").sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectWith'
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either: http://jsfiddle.net/CK9uL/135/ Thanks though for helping. Do you have any more ideas?!

Comment: The problem is not the `connectWith` property there, but the accordion itself. If you make the accordion's sections always visible, it works, but it breaks as soon as you hide the active sortable.

Comment: There also seems to be a problem with jQuery UI not activating hidden connected sortables, so event if you show them during sorting, you still can't drop anything into them.